# Can I manage product configurations in Features

Tags: wix, wix3

I have to install a product which has several configurations. Say Professional, Standard, etc.

Is it possible that the Professional and the Standard Feature contain the same common Components? If yes would there be drawbacks to such an solution?

Assume that it is ensured that only one of these features will be installed.

Example in WiX source:

```
  <Feature Id="F__P_Classic" Level="2" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" Title="Program Professional" TypicalDefault="install" Display="expand" InstallDefault="local">
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="CG__ProgramBase" />
  </Feature>
  <Feature Id="F__P_Professional" Level="2" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" Title="Program Professional" TypicalDefault="install" Display="expand" InstallDefault="local">
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="CG__ProgramBase" />
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="CG__Other" />
  </Feature>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible and it is used a lot that several features contain the same common components. I'm not aware about any drawbacks of this approach.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368579.aspx):

> Components can be shared by two or more features, that is, the same
>   component can be referred to by more than one feature.